# Blender: python script failed, no console info: worked on Blender 2.79b/2.8 with previous win10

Tags: python

I've a few python scripts that I have used before and worked.
but they do not work anymore.

at this moment when I try to run any previous working script i get  a message:
Python script failed, check the message in the system console.

However, i do not see anything in the console. I am clueless as to why it does not work

Can somebody point me to what change is needed to make it work again?

Comment: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the error message, you should open the system console, not the Blender's one. In Windows, you can open it from menu (Window → Toggle System Console):

[image]

then run the script again